# What do '!', '*', and 'x' mean in getent group?

Tags: linux, user-groups

When I run `getent group`, I notice that some groups have `*`, some have `!` and some have `x` after the group name. In fact, there are some groups which have the same name, the only difference is that one has `x` and the other has `!` and an extra user.

What is the difference among these 3 flags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `getent group` command is showing `/etc/group`, possibly augmented with other sources of information (such as `winbind`), and shows data in the same format as `/etc/group`.

According to the manual, the second field is the *encrypted password* for using the given group.  Some values are special:

**`!`** indicates that the group password would be found in the *shadow* file `/etc/gshadow` (not user-readable as `/etc/group` is).  See the *[Shadow Password How-To](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO-7.html)* for discussion.

**`x`** can have the same meaning — shadow password (see Debian [manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/system-administrator/ch-sysadmin-users.html), and [this page](http://www.tokiwinter.com/user-group-password-management-linux-solaris/) which includes a discussion of Solaris).

**`*`** may be used as a placeholder if no password was specified (see FreeBSD manual page for [`group`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=group&sektion=5&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.2-RELEASE)), as an alternative to leaving the field blank (see Linux [manual page)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/group.5.html).

According to *[In /etc/group what is the meaning of the second field?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46514/in-etc-group-what-is-the-meaning-of-the-second-field)*, the distinction between these characters is arbitrary: they were chosen to

- be visible
- not be mistaken for a valid encrypted password